# Program cannot be executed because Cygcurl-4.dll was not found

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, cmd, cygwin

**What I did:**

- I downloaded the code and applications from a c++ course for projects that I was doing online.
- I am using windows 10, everything like mingw, cygwin etc. are installed and path is also setted up in the system
- Cygwin is installed and setted up with default packages.

**Issue:** When I try to run the .exe application file it give error the Cygcurl-4.dll was not found as in below screenshot
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e60yF.png)
In Cygwin setup, I really did not found any package with this name 'Cygcurl-4.dll'
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojtkE.png)

I have also tried to find this on google but could not find how to fix this in windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lib is here

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/libcurl4.html

**libcurl4** shared object is usr/bin/**cygcurl-4.dll** for Windows (you can see in package files)

Be careful to install the x86_64 version if your system is 64 bits.

Comment: My system is 64-bit windows, I installed X86_64 version in my system, I installed it with all the default packages. But when I searched cygcurl-4.dll in the set-up process, it was not there as you can see in screenshot2 in question desc. 
I saw link in your answer for downloading cygcurl files, So can you please tell how I can install it in Cygwin only or is it separate thing? like can you please tell me the steps.

Comment: Can you search for libcurl4 in the Cygwin package manager ?

Comment: I think you should look at https://cygwin.com/install.html to install specific packages. Then install the package linked in my answer (libcurl4).